# Remove indent from table environment, and center-set the resulting table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, amsart

How can I center my table if I'd like it to be ´1.5\textwidth´?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[p]
%\centering
 \resizebox{1.5\textwidth}{!}{%
 \noindent\begin{tabular}{llllll}
 \toprule
 \multicolumn{6}{c}{Care Type} \\
 \textbf{Direct care} & \textbf{Housekeeping} & \textbf{Mealtimes} & \textbf{Medication rounds  } & \textbf{Miscellaneous} & \textbf{Personal care} \\
 \midrule
 Blood pressure measurement & Equipment cleaning& Dispensing meals& Distributing medication&Call requests&Toiletting\\
 & &&&&\\
 Weights & Cleaning patient surfaces& &Injections&Bed making &Changing\\
 & &&&&\\
 SATs~\footnote{Blood sugar saturation}  & &&&&\\
  \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}}
 \caption{Activity type and examples of each}
 \label{tab:activities}\end{table}

 \end{document}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

EDIT:

Using `\centerline{\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{...}` I get:

[image]

Using `\centering\makebox{\textwidth}{}` I get: 
[image]

Using `\begin{tabularx}{1.5\textwidth}{*6X}`

```
\begin{table}[p]
 \centering\makebox[\textwidth]
 % \centerline
  {\resizebox{1.1\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabularx}{1.5\textwidth}{*6X} % \begin{tabularx}{llllll}
 \toprule
 \multicolumn{6}{c}{Care Type} \\
 \textbf{Direct care} & \textbf{Housekeeping} & \textbf{Mealtimes} & \textbf{Medication rounds  } & \textbf{Miscellaneous} & \textbf{Personal care} \\
 \midrule
 Blood pressure measurement & Equipment cleaning& Dispensing meals& Distributing medication&Call requests&Toiletting\\
 & &&&&\\
 Weights & Cleaning patient surfaces& &Injections&Bed making &Changing\\
 & &&&&\\
 SATs~\footnote{Blood sugar saturation}  & &&&&\\
  \bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}}}
\smallskip
 \caption{Activity type and examples of each}
 \label{tab:activities}\end{table}
```

Comment: You can avoid the font-re-sizing `\resizebox` by using the `tabularx` package and `\begin{tabularx}{1.5\textwidth}{*6X}`.

Comment: Thanks!  That's helped a lot! Code pasted to give end result above :)

Comment: Your images appear to show different size tables which implies you changed the parameters to `\resizebox` (which you didn't show in your last example). Scaling text is usually a bad idea in any case, it is better to choose a suitable font size using `\small` or `\large`or as @Qrrbrbirlbel indicates using normalsize fonts and just choosing appropriate column widths. Especially making the table 50% wider than the text width seems strange choice.

Comment: why `\resizebox{1.1\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabularx}{1.5\textwidth}` not just `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}` Then you wouldn't need `\makebox` either.

Comment: ´\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}´ doesn't seem to work, the text in the box gets bunched up. I think the last edit to my post seems to give the cleanest results but it means there's a lot of faffing about with choosing `resizebox` size for every table to fit nicely...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\noindent` does nothing inside a LR box. You could use `\makebox` but simpler perhaps just use the plain TeX derived `\centerline`.  Assuming 1.5`\textwidth` fits on the paper....

(Code modified to use `\makebox` original `\centerline` version commented out.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[p]
 \centering\makebox[\textwidth]
 % \centerline
 {\resizebox{1.5\textwidth}{!}{%
 \begin{tabular}{llllll}
 \toprule
 \multicolumn{6}{c}{Care Type} \\
 \textbf{Direct care} & \textbf{Housekeeping} & \textbf{Mealtimes} & \textbf{Medication rounds  } & \textbf{Miscellaneous} & \textbf{Personal care} \\
 \midrule
 Blood pressure measurement & Equipment cleaning& Dispensing meals& Distributing medication&Call requests&Toiletting\\
 & &&&&\\
 Weights & Cleaning patient surfaces& &Injections&Bed making &Changing\\
 & &&&&\\
 SATs~\footnote{Blood sugar saturation}  & &&&&\\
  \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}}}
\smallskip
 \caption{Activity type and examples of each}
 \label{tab:activities}\end{table}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: I'd definitely use `\centering\makebox[\textwidth]{...}`; `\centerline` may give some surprises you surely are aware of. ;-)

Comment: Ah got it thank you both! What are the surprises I might encounter?

Comment: @user1134241 Code updated to show both methods .....

Comment: @user1134241 You may try `abc\centerline{def}ghi` to see what I mean.